# totaling grouped categories with multiple rows with same id

Tags: r

I have a large data frame with first 2 columns as follows. I managed to `group_count` but unable to get a column with total count. i.e 14

```
id  company group_count
1   aaa 1
1   bbb 2
1   bbb 2
1   ccc 1
1   ddd 1
1   eee 2
1   eee 2
1   fff 3
1   fff 3
1   fff 3
1   ggg 1
1   hhh 1
1   iii 1
1   jjj 1
```

I am expecting the following

```
id  company count   total count
1   aaa 1   10
1   bbb 2   10
1   bbb 2   10
1   ccc 1   10
1   ddd 1   10
1   eee 2   10
1   eee 2   10
1   fff 3   10
1   fff 3   10
1   fff 3   10
1   ggg 1   10
1   hhh 1   10
1   iii 1   10
1   jjj 1   10
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry. actually i wish to have 10 not 14

Comment: Why do you have total count as 10 when you have 14 rows with `id = 1`.

Comment: i wish to have the total of different companies

Comment: in `dplyr`, you could use `n_distinct` to get unique values. `df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(total = n_distinct(company))
`

Comment: @RonakShah this is an intuitive approach, and easy to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ave` to group `company` by `id` and calculate the length of unique elements. We first convert `company` to `factor` and then `numeric` so that the output is also `numeric`

```
ave(as.numeric(as.factor(df$company)), df$id, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))
# [1] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```